# Selecting entries from a table based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am working on a forum with a SQLITE3 backend.

My goal is to find the last 20 topics that has the most recent posts beneath them. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Topics INNER JOIN Posts ON Topics.ID = Posts.TopicID ORDER BY Posts.Modified DESC LIMIT 20
```

This is not exactly what I want as it will repeat the same topic everytime it there is a recent post under it. I just want a topic given only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the *one* latest post for each topic, and then sort by that:

```
SELECT Topics.*,
       (SELECT MAX(Modified)
        FROM Posts
        WHERE TopicID = Topics.ID
       ) AS LastModified
FROM Topics
ORDER BY LastModified DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The same can be done with a join:

```
SELECT Topics.*,
       MAX(Posts.Modified)
FROM Topics
JOIN Posts ON Topics.ID = Posts.TopicID
GROUP BY Topics.ID
ORDER BY MAX(Posts.Modified) DESC
LIMIT 20
```